# How to take the gradient of the quadratic form?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms, scalar-fields

It's stated that the gradient of:

$$\frac{1}{2}x^TAx - b^Tx +c$$

is

$$\frac{1}{2}A^Tx + \frac{1}{2}Ax - b$$

How do you grind out this equation? Or specifically, how do you get from $x^TAx$ to $A^Tx + Ax$?

Comment: did you understand the answer?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The only thing you need to remember/know is that
$$\dfrac{\partial (x^Ty)}{\partial x} = y$$
and the chain rule, which goes as
$$\dfrac{d(f(x,y))}{d x} = \dfrac{\partial (f(x,y))}{\partial x} + \dfrac{d( y^T(x))}{d x} \dfrac{\partial (f(x,y))}{\partial y}$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{d(b^Tx)}{d x} = \dfrac{d (x^Tb)}{d x} = b$$

$$\dfrac{d (x^TAx)}{d x} = \dfrac{\partial (x^Ty)}{\partial x} +  \dfrac{d (y(x)^T)}{d x} \dfrac{\partial (x^Ty)}{\partial y}$$
where $y = Ax$. And then, that is,

$$\dfrac{d (x^TAx)}{d x} = \dfrac{\partial (x^Ty)}{\partial x} +  \dfrac{d( y(x)^T)}{d x} \dfrac{\partial (x^Ty)}{\partial y} = y + \dfrac{d (x^TA^T)}{d x} x = y + A^Tx = (A+A^T)x$$

Comment: To help future generations: the full specification of the chain rule used here is $$ \frac{df(g,h)}{dx} =  \frac{d(g(x)^T)}{dx} \frac{\partial f(g,h)}{\partial g} + \frac{d(h(x)^T)}{dx} \frac{\partial f(g,h)}{\partial h} $$ The order of multiplication is very important since we're dealing with vectors!

Comment: the first statement seems wrong to me. Isn't the right statement $ \nabla_x(x^Ty) = y$? @NeilTraft

Comment: Like for example how does the answerer know where $\dfrac{\partial y^T}{\partial x}$ goes on the left or on the right or if there is a transpose or not? Or maybe I just unfamiliar with the chain rule using gradients and I only know it using partial derivatives.

Comment: Also notice that the derivative wrt a column vector is a row vector, and vice versa.  (I learned this from @copper.hat  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189434/derivative-of-quadratic-form).  However, the _gradient_ is represented as a column vector.

Comment: Where can someone learn about these differentiation rules? In my standard analysis and calculus courses, we didn't see the differentiation of matrices or vectors, only of multivariate functions

Comment: @Euler_Salter just write it as a multivariate function of the components of the vector $x$ and take the gradient. You will get the same result.

Comment: That is actually very helpful!

Comment: @Euler_Salter http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/chain/chain.html

Comment: @NeilTraft I am confused since $f$ is a scalar function then $\partial f / \partial g$ should also be a scalar function so the order shouldn't matter, what am I missing?

Comment: I don't remember what's going on here super well, but I think in the chain rule I wrote $g$ and $h$ are vector functions (for example $x^TA^T$), so the partial w.r.t. $g$ is also a vector?

Answer (score 25):

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$$f (\mathrm x) := \rm x^\top A \, x$$

Hence,

$$f (\mathrm x + h \mathrm v) = (\mathrm x + h \mathrm v)^\top \mathrm A \, (\mathrm x + h \mathrm v) = f (\mathrm x) + h \, \mathrm v^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x + h \, \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm v + h^2 \, \mathrm v^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm v$$

Thus, the **directional derivative** of $f$ in the direction of $\rm v$ at $\rm x$ is

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f (\mathrm x + h \mathrm v) - f (\mathrm x)}{h} = \mathrm v^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x + \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm v = \langle \mathrm v , \mathrm A \,\mathrm x \rangle + \langle \mathrm A^\top \mathrm x , \mathrm v \rangle = \left\langle \mathrm v , \color{blue}{\left(\mathrm A + \mathrm A^\top\right) \,\mathrm x} \right\rangle$$

Lastly, the **gradient** of $f$ with respect to $\rm x$ is

$$\nabla_{\mathrm x} \, f (\mathrm x) = \color{blue}{\left(\mathrm A + \mathrm A^\top\right) \,\mathrm x}$$

---

[multivariable-calculus](/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus) [scalar-fields](/questions/tagged/scalar-fields) [gradient](/questions/tagged/gradient) [quadratic-forms](/questions/tagged/quadratic-forms)

Comment: +1. What are that tags in your answer?

Comment: @C.F.G The tags are there to ensure I can find my answer even if the question is vandalized, tags are merged or renamed, etc. Insurance against others' misbehavior.

Comment: how were you able to swap the x^TA to A^Tx in the line with the inner products to arrive at <v, (A + A^T) x>

Comment: @Learningstatsbyexample Note that $\rm x^\top A v$ is a scalar, and a scalar is equal to its transpose. Hence, $$\rm x^\top A v = \left( \rm x^\top A v \right)^\top = \rm v^\top A^\top x$$ Does this clarify the matter?

Comment: < 7 minute response time; that is service :) Yes that helps, thanks!

Comment: What is the role of v here?

Comment: @Jackie It is a direction vector.  After all, I used the directional derivative.  The essence is that the directional derivative is the inner product of the direction vector and the gradient. Thus, I tried to isolate the direction vector and what was left is the gradient.

Answer (score 14):

I am just writing this answer for future reference and for clarity because the accepted answer is not completely correct and may case confusion.

I will use a simple proof to better understand the multiplication rule in the calculation of $\nabla\mathbf{x^TAx}$.

For $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ let: $$f(g(\mathbf{x}),h(\mathbf{x}))=\langle g(\mathbf{x}),h(\mathbf{x})\rangle=g^T(\mathbf{x})h(\mathbf{x})$$

Where:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&g(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}\\
&h(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{Ax}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

From the definition of $f$, it is obvious that $f(g(\mathbf{x}),h(\mathbf{x}))=\mathbf{x^TAx}$.

In order to calculate the derivative, we will use the following fundamental properties, where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{A^Tx}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}=\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{x^TA}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{A^T}\\
&\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{I}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Hence, from the multiplication rule (you can see the rule at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus)), we got:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dfrac{df(g(\mathbf{x}),h(\mathbf{x}))}{d\mathbf{x}}&=g^T(\mathbf{x})\dfrac{\partial h(\mathbf{x})}{\partial\mathbf{x}}+h^T(\mathbf{x})\dfrac{\partial g(\mathbf{x})}{\partial\mathbf{x}}=\\
&=\mathbf{x^T}\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{Ax}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}+(\mathbf{Ax})^T\dfrac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}=\\
&=\mathbf{x^TA}+\mathbf{x^TA^TI}=\\
&=\mathbf{x^TA}+\mathbf{x^TA^T}=\\
&=\mathbf{x^T}(\mathbf{A+A^T})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

As a result, from the definition of gradient, we got:
$$
\nabla f=\Bigg(\dfrac{df}{d\mathbf{x}}\Bigg)^T=(\mathbf{x^T}(\mathbf{A+A^T}))^T=(\mathbf{A^T+A})\mathbf{x}
$$

**Note**: The reason I did the proof this way is to be more generalizable. So you can can plug arbitrary functions $g$ and $h$ and use the above multiplication rule to derive the result.

Comment: Thank you. Till date this is the simplest of all answers. However, reading [this first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, @G.Margaritis, excuse me, coulde you help me [this equation](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/107503/gradient-of-manipulator-kinetic-energy-expressed-in-cartesian-space), i.e.,  $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \dot q^T A(q(x)) \dot q$ when matrix `A` is function of vector variable `q` and `q` is  vector function of  vector variable `x` and $ \dot x = J \dot q$

Answer (score 10):

There is another way to calculate the most complex one, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_k} \mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x}$. It only requires *nothing but partial derivative of a variable instead of a vector*.

This answer is for those who are not very familiar with partial derivative and chain rule **for vectors**, for example, me. Therefore, although it seems long, it is actually because I **write down all the details**. :)

Firstly, expanding the quadratic form yields:
$$
\begin{align}
f = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_k} \mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_k} \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_k}(\mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_j)
\end{align}
$$
Since 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_k}(\mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_j) = 
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{x}_j, && \text{if } k = i \\
\mathbf{x}_i, && \text{if } k = j \\
0, && \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
The equation is nothing but
$$
f = \sum_{j=1}^N a_{kj} \mathbf{x}_j + \sum_{i=1}^N a_{ik} \mathbf{x}_i
$$
**Almost done!** Now we only need some simplification. Recall the very simple rule that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N x_i y_i = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{bmatrix} =  \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{y}
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{align}
f &= \text{(k-th row of A) } \mathbf{x} + \text{(k-th column of A)}^T \mathbf{x}
\end{align}
$$
Now it is time to compute the gradient from partial derivative!
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x}
& = \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x}}{\partial x_1} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x}}{\partial x_k} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x}}{\partial x_N} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 
\vdots \\ \text{(k-th row of A) } \mathbf{x} + \text{(k-th column of A)}^T \mathbf{x} \\ \vdots
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \left( \begin{bmatrix} \vdots \\ \text{(k-th row of A) } \\ \vdots \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \vdots \\ \text{(k-th column of A) }^T \\ \vdots \end{bmatrix} \right) \mathbf{x} \\
&= (A + A^T)\mathbf{x}
\end{align}
$$
So we are done!! The answer is:
$$
\nabla_\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x} = (A + A^T)\mathbf{x}
$$

Answer (score 4):

**Yet another approach**.

We will utilize the following the identities

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$\left\langle A, B \right\rangle={\rm tr}(A^TB) = A:B$$ or $$\left\langle A^T, B \right\rangle ={\rm tr}(AB) = A^T:B$$
- Cyclic property of Trace/Frobenius product 
  \begin{align}
  \left\langle A, B C \right\rangle \equiv A:BC 
   &= AC^T:B\\
   &= B^TA:C\\
   &= BC : A\\
   &= {\text{etc.}} \cr
  \end{align}

Let $f(x) := \left( \frac{1}{2} x^T A x - b^T x + c \right) $.

We obtain the differential first, and then the gradient subsequently.
\begin{align}
 d\,f(x) 
&=  d\left( \frac{1}{2} x^T A x - b^T x + c \right) \\
&=  d\left( \frac{1}{2} \left( x: A x \right) - \left( b : x \right) + c \right) \\
&=  \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left( dx: A x \right) + \left( x: A dx \right) \right] - \left( b : dx \right)  \\
&=  \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left( A x : dx \right) + \left( A^Tx: dx \right) \right] - \left( b : dx \right)  \\
&=  \frac{1}{2}  \left[ \left(A + A^T  \right)x: dx \right] - \left( b : dx \right)  \\
&=  \left( \frac{1}{2}  \left[ \left(A + A^T  \right)x\right] - b \right): dx \\
\end{align}

Thus the gradient is 
$$ \eqalign {
 \frac { \partial} {\partial x}f(x) &=  \frac{1}{2}  \left[ \left(A + A^T  \right)x\right] - b \\ &=   \frac{1}{2} A^T x +  \frac{1}{2} A x - b . \cr
} $$

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I learned, with differentials. One only needs the product rule. I'll respond to the final part of the question, "Or specifically, how do you get from $x^TAx$ to $A^Tx + Ax$?"

Let $f(x) = x^T A x$. Then, to make the application of the production rule absolutely clear, let $g(x) = x^T$ and $h(x) = Ax$ so that $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$. Then by the product rule,
$$df(x) = dg(x)h(x) + g(x)*dh(x)$$
We can compute
$$
dg(x) = d(x^T) = (dx)^T
$$ and $$
dh(x) = A dx
$$
this latter one also by the product rule.

Then we have
$$
df = (dx)^T Ax + x^T Adx
$$
Now we want to get all the $dx$ term on the right. Since each term has dimension 1x1 (scalar), we can take the transpose of $(dx)^T Ax$ without changing its value, leaving
$$
df = x^T A^T dx + x^T A dx = x^T (A^T+A) dx
$$
By definition $df = (\nabla f)^T dx$. Thus we have
$$
\nabla f = (A^T + A)x
$$