# Proof relating to Orthogonal Complement

Tags: linear-algebra

> **a.)** Show that if $A=A^T$ is a symmetric matrix, then $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ has a
>   solution iff b is orthogonal to $\ker A$.
>
> **b.)** Prove that if $K$ is a positive semi-definite matrix and $\mathbf{f}\notin
>  \operatorname{rng}K$, then the quadratic function $$p(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T}K\mathbf{x} -2\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{f} + c$$ has no
>   minimum value.
>
> **c.)** Suppose $\{\mathbf{v_1},\ \cdots,\ \mathbf{v_n}\}$ span a subspace $V \subset \mathbb{R}^m$.
>   Prove that $\mathbf{w}$ is orthogonal to $V$ iff $\mathbf{w}\in \operatorname{coker}A$ where
>   $A=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{v_1} & \mathbf{v_2} & \cdots & \mathbf{v_n}\end{pmatrix}$ is the matrix with the indicated columns.

My attempt:

**a.)** We know that $A=A^\mathrm{T}$, then a vector $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ lies in $\ker A$ iff $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$.

By matrix multiplication we know that the $i^{\text{th}}$ entry of $A\mathbf{x}$ equals the vector product of the $i^{\text{th}}$ row $\mathbf{r_i}^T$ of $A$ and $\mathbf{x}$, hence $\mathbf{r_i}^{T}\cdot \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{r_i} \cdot  \mathbf{x} = 0$ iff $\mathbf{x}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{r_i}$.

Therefore $\mathbf{x}\in \ker A$ iff $\mathbf{x}$ is orthogonal to all the rows of $A$.  Thus $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ has a solution iff $\mathbf{b}$ is orthogonal to $\ker A$. **Is this correct?**

**b.)** I do not know how to do this

**c.)** In this do I have to prove that $\mathbf{w} \in \operatorname{coker}A$ is orthogonal to the range of $A$? I am not exactly sure what they are asking.

Comment: Part b seems a bit weird. If $\mathbf{f} \notin \operatorname{rng}(K)$ then there is no minimum. Otherwise, there is a global minimum, just that it's not unique.

Comment: @EuYu oops, you are right. I forgot to put the not equal sign. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **a**, your argument is showing that the rowspace is the orthogonal complement of the nullspace. That is not what the question is asking (although it is related). Notice that $\mathbf{b}$ is an element in the columnspace of $A$. The columnspace, rowspace and nullspace of a symmetric matrix are related in a very specific manner. See if you can use these relations.

For part **b**, consider the critical points of the quadratic form. Where do they occur? Does your function have any?

For **c**, what can you say about the left-nullspace and the columnspace of a matrix?

Comment: Thanks for the advice! For a.) and c.) b is an element of the columnspace so I have to show that the columnspace is orthogonal to the left-nullspace? For b.) they occur when it is minimized but how can I find that?

Comment: Well, for a symmetric matrix, the columnspace _is_ the rowspace.

Comment: There is where I am confused because $A^T=A$ so then I just have to show the rowspace is orthogonal?

Comment: $A^\mathrm{T} = A$ means that the rows and the columns of the matrix coincide. So of course the rowspace and the columnspace of the matrix coincide. Your vector $\mathbf{b}$ is a vector in the columnspace of $A$ and hence it's a vector in the rowspace of $A$. For part b, littleO's solution is perhaps more natural but taking critical points is certainly easier to think of. The gradient of a quadratic form takes on a very specific form. See this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222894/how-to-take-the-gradient-of-the-quadratic-form) for example.

Comment: So I just had to clarify in my proof that "the rowspace and the columnspace of the matrix coincide where vector b is a vector in the columnspace of A and hence it's a vector in the rowspace of A" then it will be suffice ? And thanks for the link I am going to take a look at it now!

Comment: Well, you have to understand _why_ it suffices. The full chain of reasoning is as follows: There is a solution to $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ if and only if $\mathbf{b}$ is in the columnspace of $A$. This happens if and only if $\mathbf{b}$ is in the rowspace of $A$ (because $A$ is symmetric). A vector is in the rowspace of a matrix if and only if it is in the orthogonal complement of the kernel (because the rowspace _is_ the orthogonal complement of the kernel). So all in all, there is a solution if and only if $\mathbf{b}$ is in the orthogonal complement of the kernel.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that up! I understand the mistakes in my reasoning now with your help.

Comment: Do you understand how part c works?

Comment: I was just going to ask you to clear that up for me too. For c, when they say "Suppose $\{\mathbf{v_1},\ \cdots,\ \mathbf{v_n}\}$ span a subspace $V \subset \mathbb{R}^m$." are they saying it lies in the range of V so then I must show that coker is orthogonal to the range?

Comment: Would you like to go into chat? This seems to be getting too long.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6456/discussion-between-euyu-and-diimension)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume $A$ has real entries.

For part a),
\begin{align*}
& u \in R(A)^{\perp} \\
\iff & \langle u, y \rangle = 0 \, \forall \, y \in R(A) \\
\iff & \langle u, Ax \rangle = 0 \, \forall \, x \\
\iff & \langle A^T u, x \rangle = 0 \, \forall \, x \\
\iff & A^T u = 0 \\
\iff & u \in N(A^T).
\end{align*}
This shows that $N(A^T)$ is the orthogonal complement of $R(A)$.  Because $A$
is symmetric, $N(A)$ is the orthogonal complement of $R(A)$.  Hence $b \in R(A)$
if and only if $b$ is orthogonal to $N(A)$.

For part b), let $v$ be the projection of $f$ onto $N(A)$.  Note that $v^T f = \|v\|^2 \neq 0$
and the function
\begin{align*}
g(\alpha) &= p(\alpha v) \\
&= -2\alpha v^T f + c
\end{align*}
is unbounded below.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't understand the notation you are using in part a. Do you mind if you can explain the proof by words?

Comment: I think I have a proof for a). Let $\mathbf t \in \text{ker}A$ and $\mathbf x$ such that $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$.

A linear operator $A$ is symmetric, with respect of $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$, iff $
\langle A\mathbf v, \mathbf w\rangle = \langle\mathbf v,A\mathbf w\rangle\ \forall \mathbf v, \mathbf w \in V $

If you substitute $\mathbf v=\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf w=\mathbf t$ you get
$ \langle A\mathbf x, \mathbf t\rangle = \langle \mathbf x, A\mathbf t\rangle \Rightarrow \langle\mathbf b, t\rangle = \langle\mathbf x, \underline O\rangle=0 $

So $\mathbf b$ is orthogonal to $\text{ker}A$.