# Prove a special gradient(MML exercise)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a useful formula for gradients from Math for Machine Learning Book(Deisenroth et al.) 
In 5.107 equation, 
$
\frac{\partial x^T B x}{\partial x} = x^T(B+B^T), \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}^{a}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{a \times a}
$

I can't understand how it can be solved like that.

Also, if I have inverse B, 
$
\frac{\partial x^T B^{-1} x}{\partial x} = x^T(B^{-1}+(B^{-1})^T)
$

Is this true?

Comment: The first question has been asked and answered countless times on this website. Please search on approach0.xyz for it.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1034444/81360) for instance

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem.