# Clean/simple way of computing $\nabla f(U U^\mathsf{T})$ with respect to $U$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Let $f(X)$ be a matrix function which takes in an $n \times n$ matrix $X$ and spits out something in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ for some $r << n$. I was reading a paper which stated without explanation that the gradient of $f$ with respect to $U$ is

$$
\left(\nabla f (U U^\mathsf{T}) + \nabla f(U U^\mathsf{T})^\mathsf{T}\right) \cdot U.
$$

The gradient of $f$ with respect to $X$ is naturally defined as the matrix $\nabla f(X) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that

$$
[\nabla f(X)]_{ij} = \frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial x_{ij}}.
$$

I spent a significant amount of time trying to derive this using the chain rule for multivariate functions. I.e., I thought of $f : \mathbb{R^{n^2}} \to \mathbb{R}$ as being precomposed by $g : \mathbb{R}^{n \times r} \to \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ defined by $g(U) = U U^\mathsf{T}$. But I don't see how the fact given follows easily from this. It could be that I'm just far too used to thinking about gradients as vectors, and I can't translate to these matrix functions.

Ultimately, I gave up on that approach and verified the identity by working with individual partial derivatives. **But my question is, is there a neat way to derive this fact without resorting to working with partial derivatives?**

If there is, I really want to know it, because I find that I struggle to compute derivatives of matrix functions. How would someone experienced in this area approach this problem? Thank you!

**EDIT:** Thanks to @greg's answer, I have decided to study (matrix) differentials. Here are some resources (in order from favorite to least favorite; but all three are useful) I found which might help others who stumble upon this question:

https://tminka.github.io/papers/matrix/

http://artem.sobolev.name/posts/2017-01-29-matrix-and-vector-calculus-via-differentials.html

http://thousandfold.net/cz/2013/11/12/a-useful-trick-for-computing-gradients-w-r-t-matrix-arguments-with-some-examples/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\b{\big\|}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$Given
$$\eqalign{
f = f(X)\qquad G = \p{f}{X}\qquad X = UU^T \\
}$$
Attack the problem in three steps: write the differential in terms of $X$,
change the independent variable from $X\to U$,
and extract the new gradient.
$$\eqalign{
df &= G:dX \\
 &= G:\left(dU\,U^T+U\,dU^T\right) \\
 &= \left(G+G^T\right):dU\,U^T \\
 &= \left(G+G^T\right)U:dU \\
\p{f}{U} &= \left(G+G^T\right)U \\\\
}$$

---

In the above steps, a colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \\
A:A &= \b A\b^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such products to be rearranged in many equivalent ways
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A = B^T:A^T \\
CA:B &= C:BA^T = A:C^TB \\
}$$
Note that the matrix on each side of the colon have the same dimensions.

The Frobenius product also interacts nicely with the Hadamard and Kronecker products
$$\eqalign{
A:(B\odot C) &= (A\odot B):C
   \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} C_{ij} \\
(A\otimes B):(E\otimes F) &= (A:E)\otimes(B:F) \\\\
}$$

---

As you have discovered, the chain rule can be difficult to apply in matrix calculus, because the gradient operation changes the tensorial character of a variable.

For instance, the gradient of a vector with respect to another vector is a matrix. But matrix multiplication is non-commutative, which gums up the chain rule.

Worse, the gradient of a matrix wrt a vector is a third-order **tensor**. Such a tensor is difficult to calculate, awkward to work with algebraically, and doesn't fit into standard matrix notation -- which forces you to resort to ugly hacks like **component-wise derivatives**.

The beauty of the differential approach is that the differential of a matrix *acts* like a matrix. In particular, it obeys all of the rules of matrix algebra, so it is much easier to handle.

Comment: Component-wise derivatives are ugly but I admit that I am not fully convinced of a result until I compute partial derivatives with respect to components. Maybe it is some sort of OCD.

Comment: @Miguel Don't get the wrong idea, I am a strong proponent of index notation. I simply **detest** the bastardized notation that I see so often on this site, which employs indexed vectors and matrices, rather than working with actual tensor components.

Comment: Wow! This seems fantastic, although to be honest it goes a bit over my head. I've learned multivariable calculus and some real analysis (parts of Baby Rudin), but I've never seen differentials (let alone matrix differentials) manipulated in this way. Is there a resource you recommend for learning more about the math behind the technique you showed?

Comment: @nkyraf33 Your experience is not unusual. The differential is sadly neglected in math education, and discussion of _matrix_ differentials is rarer still. I would recommend poking around on this site; there are lots of interesting questions and answers.