# Gradient of $f(x) = x^TP^{-1}x$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I saw from this link how to calculate the gradient of the function f(x)=$x^TPx$:
 [How to calculate gradient of $x^TAx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482742/how-to-calculate-gradient-of-xtax)

Does this proof still hold true when the inverse of the P-matrix is used? My assumption is that it should, as I could just let a matrix $A=P^{-1}$, and then follow the steps outlined in the link to arrive at $f'(x)=\nabla f=x^T(A+A^T)$ or for my specific question $f'(x)=\nabla f=x^T(P^{-1}+(P^{-1})^T)$

Are there any holes in this logic?

Comment: You are right, you can use the other result directly by substituting $A = P^{-1}$; nothing more is needed.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this proof still hold true when the inverse of the P-matrix is used?

Yes it does. Just replace $A = P^{-1}$ and you will get
$$f'(x)=\nabla f=x^T(P^{-1}+P^{-T}) $$
where $P^{-T} = (P^{-1})^T = (P^T)^{-1}$.