# Gradient of 2-norm squared

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, normed-spaces, scalar-fields

Could someone please provide a proof for why the gradient of the squared $2$-norm of $x$ is equal to $2x$?

$$\nabla\|x\|_2^2 = 2x$$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894/339790)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Use the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm).
If $$f(x)=\|x\|^2_2= \left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 \right)^{1/2}\right)^{2}=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2  ,$$
then 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}f(x)  =\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2=\sum_{k=1}^n \underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}x_k^2}_{\substack{=0, \ \text{ if } j \neq k,\\=2x_j, \ \text{ else }}}= 2x_j.$$
It follows that
$$\nabla f(x) = 2x.$$

Comment: Thanks. One follow up question, does this still hold if x is complex?

Comment: Isn't the L2 norm defined as: $$f(x)=\|x\|^2_2= \left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2 \right)^{1/2}\right)^{2}=\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2$$, there is an absolute value sign surrounding $x_k$, so when you take the derivative what should pop out is $2|x_j|$ not just $2x_j$, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Lookbehindyou well |t|^2 = t^2 for any $t\in\Bbb R$. Moreover, note that $\frac{d}{t}|t|^2 = 2|t|\operatorname{sign}(t)=2t$, where $\operatorname{sign}$ is the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)

Comment: Could you please explain what happened to the sigma in the last step?

Comment: @Gigili: If $k\neq j$, then $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}x_k^2=0$. Then, $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}x_k^2=0+...+0+2x_j+0+...+0=2x_j.$$

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @Surb Thank you for the clarification.  However, is this an $\ell_2$ norm? Or an $L_2$ norm? Aren't those for the *infinite*-dimensional cases (countable and otherwise)? I did *not* remove any tags. I added the tag [scalar-fields] because the powers-that-be [removed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32505/339790) the tag [gradient], which makes it hard to find questions on computing the gradient of a scalar field.

Comment: @Surb I introduced neither $\ell^2$ nor $L^2$. I used "$2$-norm" instead. Also, tags are not necessarily for humans.  If Stack Exchange is minimally well-designed, then proper tagging should lead to more relevant entries in the `Related` column, which should make it easier (for humans) to find duplicates or related questions. The lack of discipline and rigor in tagging is a major weakness of Math SE, in my opinion.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Faire enough :).

Answer (score 42):

Another approach that extends to more general settings is to use the connection between the norm and the inner product,
$$\|x\|^2 = (x,x).$$

We have the finite difference,
\begin{align}
\|x+sh\|^2 - \|x\|^2 &= (x+sh,x+sh) - (x,x) \\
&= (x,x) + 2s(x,h) + s^2(h,h) - (x,x) \\
&= 2s(x,h) + s^2(h,h).
\end{align}

The gradient acting in the direction $h$ is the limit of this finite difference as the stepsize goes to zero,
\begin{align}
(\nabla\|x\|^2, h) &:= \lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{s}\left[\|x+sh\|^2 - \|x\|^2\right] \\
&= \lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{s}\left[2s(x,h) + s^2(h,h)\right] \\
&= (2x,h).
\end{align}
Since this holds for any direction $h$, the gradient must be $\nabla \|x\|^2 = 2x$.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is rigorous enough to count as a proof, but an elegant way to obtain derivatives of vector expressions is to use matrix differential calculus.

Let $y = \lVert x \rVert_2^2 = x^{T} x$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.
Using the product rule, the differential of $y$ is
$$
dy = dx^{T} x + x^{T} dx = 2 x^{T} dx
$$

We can then set
$$
dy = \frac{dy}{dx} dx = (\nabla_{x} y)^{T} dx = 2x^{T} dx
$$
where $dy/dx \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$ is called the derivative (a linear operator) and $\nabla_{x} y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is called the gradient (a vector).

Now we can see $\nabla_{x} y = 2 x$.

---

If $x$ is complex, the *complex* derivative does not exist because $z \mapsto |z|^{2}$ is not a holomorphic function.

We can, however, instead consider the real derivatives with respect to the two components of $x$.
Let $x = u + i v$.
With this definition, $y$ is a real function of $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ defined by
$$
y = x^* x = (u + i v)^* (u + i v) = u^T u - v^T v
$$
Taking the differential
$$
dy = 2 u^T du - 2 v^T dv = \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} du + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} dv
$$
and therefore
$$
\nabla_{u} y = 2 u \enspace , \qquad \nabla_{v} y = -2 v
$$

---

For an introduction to matrix differential calculus, see [the lecture of Geoff Gordon on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By00gUNLY1w#t=9m40) or [the paper on matrix derivatives of Mike Giles](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/files/NA-08-01.pdf).

Comment: sorry me, why $x^T dx + dx^T x = 2x^T dx$ ? 
I suppose, that dx^T = dx, because it is number, but what we can do with x + x^T ..

Comment: Actually $dx$ has the same dimension as $x$, both are in $R^n$

Comment: In case it wasn't clear - for $a, b \in R^n$, we have $a^T b = b^T a = \sum_i a_i b_i$

Answer (score 0):

Here an other simple proof using directly the definition of differentiability at a point.

1-But first let's remmeber that $f(\vec{x})$ is said to be differentaible at point $x$ if $\forall \vec{h}$ you have that you can writte $ f(\vec{x}+ \vec{h})= f(\vec{x}) + L(\vec{h}) + o(\vec{h})$ with $L(\vec{h})$ a linear mapping in $\vec{h}$ and $\lim_{\vec{h} \to \vec{0}} || \frac{o(\vec{h})} {||\vec{h}||} ||$

2-Here $f(\vec{x})= ||\vec{x}||^2$
$$||\vec{x}+\vec{h}||^2 = ||\vec{x}||^2 + || \vec{h}||^2 + <\vec{x}|\vec{h}> + <\vec{h}|\vec{x}> = f(\vec{x})  + <\vec{x}|\vec{h}> + <\vec{h}|\vec{x}> + || \vec{h}||^2 $$
We note $o(\vec{h}) = || \vec{h}||^2 \Rightarrow \lim_{\vec{h} \to \vec{0}} || \frac{||\vec{h}||^2} {||\vec{h}||} || = \lim_{\vec{h} \to \vec{0}} || \vec{h}|| = 0$
Obviously $L( \vec{h}) = <\vec{x}|\vec{h}> + <\vec{h}|\vec{x}>$ as it is a linear mapping in $\vec{h}$ because we work with real number we get that $<\vec{x}|\vec{h}> = <\vec{h}|\vec{x}> \Rightarrow <\vec{x}|\vec{h}> + <\vec{h}|\vec{x}> = 2<\vec{x}|\vec{h}> $

3- Now again by definition the unique vector $ \vec{\nabla f( \vec{x})}$ satisfying $ 2<\vec{x}|\vec{h}> = <\vec{\nabla f( \vec{x})}| \vec{h}> $ is the gradient.
Thus it cames trivially that $\vec{\nabla f( \vec{x})} = 2\vec{x} $