# Is the l2-norm squared generated from an inner product?

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, machine-learning, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

We know that the l2-norm is generated from an inner product by using the parallelogram law.

[proof that l2 norm is generated from inner product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoz1n.png)

What about the squared of the $l_2$-norm? Is that generated from an inner product? I've tried to solve this using the parallelogram law but im not sure of my answer and i think it is no.

But in kernel ridge regression we use the $l_2$-norm squared, and according to the representer theorem the $l_2$-norm squared has to correspond to an inner product.

Will anyone be kind to show the proof to me? Many Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the "norm" $\|f\|_4 = \left(\int_{\Omega} |f(x)|^4\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ ?

Comment: i mean the l2 norm squared, as defined in the comment section in this thread ( sorry dont know how to write maths formulas here)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883016/gradient-of-l2-norm-squared/883024

Comment: Oh! You mean $\|x\|^2$, rather than $\|x\|$?

Comment: You mean $\|(x_1,\dots,x_n)\| := x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$? If this is the case, then $\|\cdot\|$ is not a norm since $\|a(x_1,\dots,x_n)\| \neq |a|\|(x_1,\dots,x_n)\|$.

Comment: yes, not too sure of the convention, is ||x|| the l2 or l1 norm? if ||x|| is the l2 norm then yes that is what i meant. used to seeing a subscript 2 in the l2 norm equation

Comment: @fxl Forget about indexes, it is the least important thing. What really matters is if you mean the "norm" where you add the squares of the entries of the vector.

Comment: yes, azifmedrano you have the equation correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $V$ is a real vector space, a *norm* on $V$ is a function $\|\cdot\| : V \to \mathbb R$, where $v \mapsto \|v\|$, such that the following properties holds:

- For any $v \in V$, $\|v\| \geq 0$; and $\|v\| = 0$ only if $v$ is the zero vector.
- For any $v \in V$ and $a \in \mathbb R$, $\|av\| = |a|\|v\|$.
- For every pair of vectors $v$ and $w$ in $V$, $\|v+w\| \leq \|v\|+\|w\|$.

Then, if $V = \mathbb R^n$ and we define $\|(x_1,\dots,x_n)\|$ by $x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$, $\|\cdot\|$ is not a norm on $V$ since the second property doesn't holds for every $a \in \mathbb R$, unless $a = \pm 1$.

Comment: thx for this azifmedrano, so it does not even make sense to think of the l2 norm squared as a norm in the first place...you are just squaring the norm.....i get it now and have read the theorem wrongly... thanks for the definition, helps alot