# Derivative of $\frac{\partial f(X^{\top}X)}{\partial X}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

The task is to prove that for any matrix $X$ and differentiable scalar function $f$, the following holds:

$$
\frac{\partial f(X^\top X)}{\partial X} = 2{X}\frac{\partial f(X^\top X)}{\partial (X^\top X)}.
$$

Following the Chain Rule, I could already denote that:

$$
\frac{\partial f(X^\top X)}{\partial X} = \frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial X} = \frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial X} = \frac{\partial f(X^\top X)}{\partial (X^\top X)}\frac{\partial X^\top X}{\partial X}
$$

for $u$ being a function of $X$ with $u(X) = X^{\top}X$

Now, I have difficulty proving that $\dfrac{\partial (X^{\top}X)}{\partial X} = 2X$.

I know from [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883016/gradient-of-2-norm-squared) as well as The Matrix Cookbook, that for a vector x, the following holds for the squared Euclidian Norm: $\dfrac{||\textbf{x}||^2_2}{\partial x} = \dfrac{||x^{\top} x||_2}{\partial x} = 2x$, but how can I go from this to rigorously arguing the same for $\dfrac{\partial f(X^{\top} X)}{\partial X} $? Or is there an even simpler way to do it?

Any hints would be appreciated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$The matrix inner product (denoted by a colon) is extremely useful in these sorts of problems.
It is essentially a product notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot, or Frobenius product.

When applied to vectors $(n={\tt1})$ it reduces to an ordinary dot product.

Terms in a Frobenius product can be rearranged in many useful ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A &= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
Define $\:Y=X^TX\:$ and assume that we know the gradient
$\:G=\large{\grad fY}$

Use  $G$ to calculate the *differential* of the function, then perform a change variables from $Y\to X.\;$ Then recover the gradient with respect to $X$
$$\eqalign{
df &= G:dY \\
 &= G:\LR{dX^TX+X^TdX} \\
 &= 2\,G:\LR{X^TdX} \\
 &= \LR{2XG}:dX \\
\grad fX &= 2XG \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the notation $\frac{\partial \alpha (X)}{\partial X}$ means, but you can write $f(X^\top X)=(f\circ g\circ h)(X)$ for $h(X):=(X^\top ,X)$ and $g(X,Y):=XY$, then using the Fréchet derivative and for every matrix $H$ the chain rule gives
$$
\begin{align*}
\partial [f(X^\top X)]H&=(\partial f\circ g\circ h)(X)(\partial g\circ h)(X)\partial h(X)H\\
&=\partial f(X^\top X)\partial g(X^\top ,X)\partial h(X)H\\
&=\partial f(X^\top X)\partial g(X^\top ,X)(H^\top ,H)\\
&=\partial f(X^\top X)(X^\top H+H^\top X)
\end{align*}
$$

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Before proving this claim, it is important to clarify the notation. Given a function $f:M_{m\times n}(\Bbb C)\to \Bbb C$, we define its derivative $\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial X}$ as another $m\times n$ matrix $D_f=[d_{i,j}]_{m\times n}$ such that
$$
d_{i,j}=\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial x_{i,j}},
$$
where the differentiation has been performed w.r.t. $X=[x_{i,j}]_{m\times n}$. Now, by defining $Y=X^TX=[y_{i,j}]_{n\times n}$, we have $y_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^mx_{k,i}x_{k,j}$ and we can write
$$
\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial x_{i,j}}{
=
\sum_{\mu=1}^n\sum_{\nu=1}^n\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{\mu,\nu}}\frac{\partial y_{\mu,\nu}}{\partial x_{i,j}}
\\=
\sum_{\mu=1}^n\sum_{\nu=1}^n\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{\mu,\nu}}\frac{\partial \sum_{\kappa=1}^mx_{\kappa,\mu}x_{\kappa,\nu}}{\partial x_{i,j}}
\\=
\sum_{\mu=1\\\mu\ne j}^n\sum_{\nu=1\\\nu\ne j}^n\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{\mu,\nu}}\frac{\partial \sum_{\kappa=1}^mx_{\kappa,\mu}x_{\kappa,\nu}}{\partial x_{i,j}}
\\+
\sum_{\nu=1\\\nu\ne j}^n\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{j,\nu}}\frac{\partial \sum_{\kappa=1}^mx_{\kappa,j}x_{\kappa,\nu}}{\partial x_{i,j}}
\\+
\sum_{\mu=1\\\mu\ne j}^n\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{\mu,j}}\frac{\partial \sum_{\kappa=1}^mx_{\kappa,\mu}x_{\kappa,j}}{\partial x_{i,j}}
\\+
\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{j,j}}\frac{\partial \sum_{\kappa=1}^mx_{\kappa,j}x_{\kappa,j}}{\partial x_{i,j}}
\\=
0
+
\sum_{\nu=1\\\nu\ne j}^n\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{j,\nu}}x_{i,\nu}
+
\sum_{\mu=1\\\mu\ne j}^n\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{\mu,j}}x_{i,\mu}
+
\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{j,j}}2x_{i,j}
\\=
\sum_{\nu=1\\\nu\ne j}^n\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{j,\nu}}2x_{i,\nu}
+
\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{j,j}}2x_{i,j}
\\=
\sum_{\nu=1}^n\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{j,\nu}}2x_{i,\nu}.
}
$$
From here, $\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{i,j}}$ are the entries of $\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial X^TX}$. Therefore, according to definition of matrix multiplication, $\sum_{\nu=1}^n\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial y_{j,\nu}}2x_{i,\nu}$ are the entries of $2X\frac{\partial f(X^TX)}{\partial X^TX}$ and the proof is complete $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Could you briefly explain what you are summing up from line 3 to line 6 of your calculation? I can't quite follow your indexing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, the double summation is over $\mu$ and $\nu$ for $(\mu,\nu)\in\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}^2$ in the 3rd line. I split this double summation to four cases where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are both unequal to $j$, only $\mu$ is equal to $j$, only $\nu$ is equal to $j$ or both $\mu$ and $\nu$ are equal to $j$.

Comment: I see, thank you, but what is the reason for splitting it up into four cases?

Comment: The need for that is that the derivative is being calculated differently for these cases.