# Difficulty with the derivative of $L_2$ norm

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, least-squares, scalar-fields

[image: Derivative of L2 Norm]

---

So I was under the impression that the L2 norm squared of a vector x is just 2x, but the example in the screenshot I have linked to says otherwise. What gives? I can't figure out why there's an extra A transpose factor in the result for the derivative.

Comment: Because you have $f(x) = n(l(x))$, where $l(x) = Ax-b$ and $n(y) = {1\over 2} \|y\|^2$, so you need to use the chain rule. Alternatively, just compute $f(x+h)-f(x)$ and look at the terms that are linear in $h$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take the gradient of the quadratic form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222894/how-to-take-the-gradient-of-the-quadratic-form)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chain rule for this problem. But for matrix/vector problems the intermediate derivatives required by the chain rule often involve complicated 3rd and 4th order tensors.  So my preferred approach is to use successive change-of-variables within differential expressions.

Define the varible $y=Ax+b$.  Then the norm (written in terms of the [Frobenius product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product)) and its differential are
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \|y\|_F^2 \cr
   &= y:y \cr\cr
df &= 2y:dy \cr
   &= 2y:A\,dx \cr
   &= 2A^Ty:dx \cr
}$$
Since $df=\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}:dx\big),\,$ the gradient is
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2A^Ty \cr
}$$
Note that your initial impression is correct, i.e. with respect to $y$ the gradient is simply
$$\eqalign{
df &= 2y:dy \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= 2y \cr
}$$