# Take Matrix Derivative, Minimize function.

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, quadratic-forms, scalar-fields

I know $\frac{d(x^T*A*X)}{dx}=A^T*X+A*X$.
How can I **use** this to express: $\frac{dR(w)}{dw}$ where $R(w)$ is $(X*W-Y)^T*A*(X*W-Y)$?

```
X is n by d.
Y is n by 1.
w is d by 1.
A is a diagonal n by n matrix.
```

I can assume that $X^T*A*X$ is full rank. (What does this allow us to do here?!)

My guess is that I can maybe distribute the $^T$ and simplify to transform $R(w)$ into a form where the formula can be applied, but I don't see exactly how.

Below is my work, I'm not sure how to continue:

$\begin{array}{l@{}l}
R(w)
  &{}= \left(\left(W^T*X^T\right)^T-Y\right)^T*A*\left(\left(W^T*X^T\right)^T-Y\right)\\
  &{}= \left(X*W-Y\right)^T*A*\left(X*W-Y\right)\\
\end{array}$

I rewrite R(W) to try to be able to use the formula and take the derivative of R(W) with respect to w.
$\frac{d\left(X^T*A*X\right)}{dx}=A^T*X+A*X$

We take $\frac{dR(W)}{dW}$ and set it to $0$.

$\begin{array}{l@{}l}
R(w)
  &{}= \left(\left(X*W\right)^T-Y^T\right)*A*\left(X*W-Y\right)\\
  &{}= \left(\left(X*W\right)^T*A-Y^T*A\right)*\left(X*W-Y\right)\\
  &{}= \left(X*W\right)^T*A*\left(X*W\right)-\left(X*W\right)^T*A*Y-Y^T*A*X*W+Y^T*A*Y\\
\end{array}$

Not sure how to continue / take the derivative from here.

The reason I need to do this is I want to find vector w that minimizes R(w). Do I do dR(w)/dw (with respect to w, like described above) and set it to...zero?

Comment: please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your posts

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894/339790)

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, define the vector 
$$\eqalign{
 z &= Xw-y \cr
dz &= X\,dw \cr
}$$
Now write down the function in terms of the [Frobenius (:) inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and find its differential 
$$\eqalign{
 R &= z:Az \cr
dR &= dz:Az + z:A\,dz \cr
   &= (A + A^T)\,z:dz \cr
   &= (A + A^T)\,(Xw-y):X\,dw \cr
   &= X^T(A + A^T)\,(Xw-y):dw \cr
}$$
Since $dR=\Big(\frac{\partial R}{\partial w}:dw\Big),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial R}{\partial w} &= X^T(A + A^T)\,(Xw-y) \cr
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero and solving for $w$ yields
$$\eqalign{
 X^T(A + A^T)\,Xw &= X^T(A + A^T)\,y \cr
 w &= \Big(X^T(A + A^T)X\Big)^{-1}X^T(A + A^T)\,y \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks, this answer is correct. Is there a way to do this without using the Frobenius product, perhaps using something similar to what I attempted?