# Newton's method for unconstrained minimization

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^T Q x + b^T x + c.$ Prove that Newton's method finds a critical point after a single iteration.

Here $Q$ is positive definite.
For this:

I need to find first of

$\nabla f(x) =  $

$\nabla^2 f(x) = $

I am confused about how do I get gradient of this function.
Once I know the gradient, I think I can do it.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla f(x) = \frac 1 2 (Q^T+Q)x + b$ and $\nabla^2 f(x) = \frac 1 2 (Q^T + Q)$

Comment: Actually, if you want to know how it is computed have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222894/how-to-take-the-gradient-of-the-quadratic-form

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks