# Differentiating $RSS(\beta) = (y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)$ with respect to $\beta$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, least-squares, linear-regression

Suppose I have a vector $y$ of dimension $N \times 1$, and a matrix $X$ of dimension $N \times p$ and a vector $\beta$ of dimension $p \times 1$. Then I wish to differentiate the matrix equation :

$RSS(\beta) = (y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)$ with respect to $\beta$.

I know that in general for a vector $x$ that $\frac{d}{dx} x^Tx = 2x$, so that
the result should be something like (using the chain rule) :

$\frac {\partial RSS}{\partial \beta} = 2 (y-X\beta) \frac {\partial} {\partial \beta} (y-X\beta)$, and that the resulting answer is $-2 X^T(y-X\beta)$, but I am confused how this is achieved. Why is $X^T$ on the left side? I'm not too experienced with differentiating matrix equations and any general concept here to see this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894/339790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
$$R(\beta) = (y^T - \beta^T X^T)(y-X\beta) = y^Ty-y^TX\beta-\beta^TX^Ty+\beta^TX^TX\beta.$$
Next observe that, $$(y^TX\beta)^T=\beta^TX^Ty$$ and so their derivaties are the same, (equal to $X^Ty$) and the derivative of $\beta^TX^TX\beta$ is $2X^TX\beta.$
So you have,
$$R'(\beta) = 0 - X^Ty - X^Ty+2X^TX\beta = -2X^T(y-X\beta).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\partial_i:=\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta_i}$ so $\partial_i(y-X\beta)_j=-X_{ji}$ and$$\partial_i(y-X\beta)^2=2(X\beta-y)_jX_{ji}=2X^T(X\beta-y)_i,$$i.e. $\nabla_\beta(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)=2X^T(X\beta-y)$.

Comment: Should there not be constants in some of these expressions? I understand what is meant generally I think tho.

Comment: @IntegrateThis Thanks; fixed.