# Gradient of $f(x)=(a^T x)(b^T x)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms, scalar-fields

How do you find the gradient of $f(x)=(a^T x)(b^T x)$ where $a$, $b$, and $x$ are $n$-dimensional vectors?

So, far I tried by taking a derivative with chain rule:
$$ D(f(x)) = D[(a^Tx)(b^Tx)] = (a^Tx)D(b^Tx) + (b^Tx)D((a^Tx)^T)$$ 
which leads me to:
$$ (a^Tx)b^T + (b^Tx)(a^Tx)^T$$
but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Some facts and notations before we start deriving the gradient:

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$\left\langle A, B C\right\rangle={\rm tr}(A^TBC) := A : B C$$
- Cyclic properties of Trace/Frobenius product 
  \begin{align}
  A : B C 
   &= BC : A \\
   &= A C^T   :  B  \\
   &= {\text{etc.}} \cr
  \end{align}

Towards this end, we rewrite your function
\begin{align}
f(x) &= a^T x b^T x\\
     &= (a^Tx)^T b^Tx \\ 
     &= a^Tx : b^T x
\end{align}

Now, we can obtain the differential first, and then the gradient of $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$.
\begin{align}
df(x)  
&= \left( a^T dx: b^T x \right) + \left( a^T x: b^T dx \right) \\
&= \left( b^T x : a^T dx \right) + \left( a^T x: b^T dx \right) \\
&= \left( ab^T x : dx \right) + \left( ba^T x: dx \right) \\
\end{align}

Thus, the gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = a b^T x  + ba^T x.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$$f (\mathrm x) := \left( \mathrm a^\top \mathrm x \right) \left( \mathrm b^\top \mathrm x \right) = \left( \mathrm x^\top \mathrm a \right) \left( \mathrm b^\top \mathrm x \right) = \mathrm x^\top \mathrm a \mathrm b^\top \mathrm x$$

whose [gradient](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894/339790) is

$$\nabla f (\mathrm x) = \color{blue}{\left(\mathrm a \mathrm b^\top + \mathrm b \mathrm a^\top \right) \mathrm x}$$

---

[multivariable-calculus](/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus) [scalar-fields](/questions/tagged/scalar-fields) [quadratic-forms](/questions/tagged/quadratic-forms) [gradient](/questions/tagged/gradient)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to solve the problem:

$$f(x)=(a^Tx)(b^Tx)$$
$$f(x)=\left(\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2&...&a_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\...\\x_n\end{bmatrix}\right)\left(\begin{bmatrix}b_1&b_2&...&b_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\...\\x_n\end{bmatrix}\right)$$
$$f(x)=(a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_nx_n)(b_1x_1+b_2x_2+...+b_nx_n)$$
Now we need to take the partial derivative with respect to $x_i$:
$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_i}}=(a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_nx_n)\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}(b_1x_1+b_2x_2+...+b_nx_n) + \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}(a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_nx_n)(b_1x_1+b_2x_2+...+b_nx_n)$$
$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_i}}=(a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_nx_n)b_i + a_i(b_1x_1+b_2x_2+...+b_nx_n)$$
When we create the gradient by evaluating $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_i}}$ for every value of $i$ we get:
$$\nabla{f}=\begin{bmatrix}a^Tx*b_1+b^Tx*a_1\\a^Tx*b_2+b^Tx*a_2\\...\\a^Tx*b_n+b^Tx*a_n\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\nabla{f}=(a^Tx)*b + (b^Tx)*a$$

I hope this helps!