# Matrix Differentiation Chain Rule

Tags: matrices, implicit-differentiation, chain-rule

I want to compute the derivative of a scalar with respect to a matrix where the scalar is linked with the matrix through a vector. 
For instance let the scalar be $l = (x-c)^T (x-c)$ where $x,c$ are vectors $\in \mathbb{R}^p $
And $x = Az$ where A is a $pxq$ matrix.

Now if I want to calculate $\frac{d l}{d A}$ then I can write $\frac{d l}{d A} =\frac{d l}{d x} \frac{d x}{d A}$

$\frac{d l}{d x}$ is easy to compute but I need help for $\frac{d x}{d A}$

Comment: You don't want to do that. $\frac{\partial x}{\partial A}$ is some 3 dimensional array. Your best bet is to write $l$ in terms of $A$ and directly take the derivative from there.

Comment: @NinadMunshi right but how can I do that?

Comment: So, you want to compute the gradient $\nabla_A \| A z - c \|_2^2$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes indeed. Can you help?

Comment: One method is to compute the directional derivative and massage things till something that looks like an inner product comes out. Take a look at [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3357120/339790). Yes, the gradient is with respect to a vector rather than a matrix, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the vector $w=(Az-c)\;$ and write the function as
$\,\ell=\|w\|^2$

Then calculate the gradient (wrt $w$)
and change variables from $\,w\to A$
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial w} &= 2w \\
d\ell &= 2w:dw \;=\; 2w:dA\,z \;=\; 2wz^T:dA \\
\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial A} &= 2wz^T \\
}$$
where a colon denotes the Frobenius inner product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) =  B:A$$

---

**NB:** By using the differential $(d\ell)$ in the intermediate step, there was no need to calculate the third-order tensor
$\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial A}\right)$
which is hard to calculate and awkward to manipulate algebraically.