# Partial derivative of complex matrix products

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product, vectorization

I have a constraint optimization problem formulated in a diagonal matrix form:

$
    P_3:~ min_{x} \quad \|A X(t) - Y(t)\|^2 \\
    \text{subject to} \quad  X^*(t) \cdot X(t) = \mathbb{I}
$

I need to take the partial derivative of the following function wrt x of this vectorization.

$ f(X,\Lambda) = \left[ (I \otimes A)vec X  - vec Y \right]^ * \cdot \left[ (I \otimes A)vec X  - vec Y \right] - \Lambda( (\mathbb{I} \otimes X^* vec X) - vec \mathbb(I))$

X,Y,A, $\Lambda$ are diagonal matrices, * is the conjugate transpose operation.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like $L(x,\lambda)$ is supposed to be a Lagrangian. In that case it should be a scalar, not a matrix.

Comment: It is a condensed version of a multiconstraint problem. But, regardless of this new format, please , could you help me with the matrix partial derivative ??

Comment: @user3284182 The problem is that in order for $\frac{\partial L}{\partial X}$ to be representable as a matrix (as opposed to an order-3 or order-4 tensor), $L$ needs to be scalar valued. The formula that you've presented cannot possibly be correct even if all the matrices involved had real-number entries. At least, this is the case assuming that you mean what people usually are referring to when they write $\frac{\partial L}{\partial X}$.

Comment: Okay. I understood now.. Let me rephrase it .. Please look at the edited question @BenGrossmann

Comment: Since the matrices are diagonal, the problem is equivalent to
$$\eqalign{
x = {\rm diag}(X),\quad
y = {\rm diag}(Y),\quad
f = \|Ax-y\|^2_F
}$$
You can find lots of posts 
(like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3508373/357854)) which calculate the gradient of $f.\;$

Comment: @greg Thanks for your answer. But I need to find the formulation in this tensor form. Because actually, I have a constraint witch is given in a matrix form. Please see the edited question

Comment: So the matrix $X$ is diagonal **and** orthogonal. In terms of vector elements this means that $$\large{x_k = {\rm sign}(y_k/a_k) = \pm\tt1}$$

Comment: @greg, Yes.. this means that the constraint makes my x entries all have absolute values equal to 1. However, I need to find the partial derivatives anyway. Because I seek to rewrite the system with a new equation.