# Derivatives of least-squares cost function

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, least-squares

I have $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}|| Ax - b ||^2 $ for $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n, b \in \mathbb{R}^m $ and $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$

I am trying to write this as a summation, calculate the 1. and 2. derivative and then transform the result (for both derivatives) back to algebra notation.

Rewritten as a summation:
$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}|| \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{i j} xj - \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_j ||^2$

What I have trouble with is calculating the derivatives since I cannot find much on the subject.

1. Derivative (not sure if that is correct):
   $\frac{\partial f(x)_i}{\partial x_k} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\frac{1}{2}||\sum_{i=j}^{n}(a_{i j} - b_i)||^2 = \frac{1}{2}||\sum_{i=j}^{n} a_{i j} \frac{\partial f(x)_j}{\partial x_k} + 0||^2$

$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}||A||^2$

I would really appreciate if someone could show me how to solve problems like this.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894/339790

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The norm $\|\cdot\|$ is for vectors... You are using norms where it does not make sense. What you have is that

$$
f(x) =\frac 12 \|Ax -b\|^2 = \frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j - b_i\right)^2
$$

So, the derivatives are computed as

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} = \frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^m 2a_{ik}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j - b_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ik}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j - b_i\right)
$$

Comment: If I transform this back, do I end up with: f'(x) = A(Ax-b)?

Comment: No, it will actually be $A^T(Ax-b)$.

Comment: Thank you very. I now understand quite a few things more about this notation. Well, I am going to try the 2. Derivation.

Answer (score 2):

We can use matrix notation to get the results.

$$
  \|Ax - b\|^2 =
  (Ax - b)^T(Ax - b) =
  (x^TA^T - b^T)(Ax - b) =
$$
$$
  x^TA^TAx - x^TA^T b - b^T Ax + b^T b =
  x^TA^TAx - 2 x^TA^T b + b^T b
$$

Not the derivatives:
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}b^T b = 0
$$

$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}2 x^T A^T b = 
   2 A^T b \> \frac{\partial}{\partial x}x^T = 
   2 A^T b
$$

$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}x^TA^TAx = A^TA \> \frac{\partial}{\partial x}x^Tx = 2 A^TAx
$$

Finally we get
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\|Ax - b\|^2 = A^TAx - A^T b
$$

*Here we use the property of the transposition operation $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$*

Comment: You can just use the chain rule so you don't have to expand everything. If $f(x) = (1/2) \| Ax - b \|^2$ then $f(x) = g(h(x))$ where $h(x) = Ax - b$ and $g(u) = (1/2) \| u \|^2$. Note that $h'(x) = A$ and $g'(u) = u^T$. By the chain rule, $f'(x) = g'(h(x)) h'(x) = (Ax - b)^T A$. If we use the convention that the gradient is a column vector, then $\nabla f(x) = f'(x)^T = A^T(Ax - b)$.

Comment: In other words, the chain rule just immediately tells us that $f'(x) = (Ax - b)^T A$. So $\nabla f(x) = A^T (Ax - b)$.

Comment: Is the second derivation A^(T+1)?

Comment: The second derivative should be $A^T A$. The term $A^T b$ do not depend on $x$, so the derivative equals to zero. The term $A^T A x$ is linear on $x$, so the derivative is $A^TA$.

Comment: Thanks. A^(T+1) = A^T A if I am not mistaken, so I finally got it right.