# Why does standard quadratic programming contain $\dfrac{1}{2}$ in the objective function?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

[image]

Does the $\dfrac{1}{2}$ provide any of computation convenience?

Comment: This way, given a quadratic polynomial in several variables, $Q$ is precisely the Hessian matrix of second derivatives. If all coefficients in the polynomial are integers, this way $Q$ has all integer elements.

Comment: This way, the unconstrained solution is $-Q^{-1}c$

Comment: You can say it is for computation convenience. Assuming $Q$ is symmetric, the gradient of $x^T Q x$ with respect to $x$ is $2 Qx$. Therefore, $\frac{1}{2}$ constant can cancel the scaling $2$ in the gradient.

Comment: Because: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894/339790