# Find a $p $ such that $q \mapsto q^Tg + 2 p^T S q + q^T S q$ is the constant zero map.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> I have the following problem: given the map
> $$p \mapsto p^T g + p^T S p$$
> where the operation in the first term of the sum is the dot product, and in the second matrix multiplication, I would like to find its critical points.

[The context for the interested is that $g$ and $S $ represents the gradient and the Hessian, respectively, of a twice differentiable map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$.]

My approach is to differentiate the map w.r.t. $p $. Then, assuming that $S $ is symmetric, I get that for each $p$ the derivative is the map

$$q \mapsto q^Tg + 2 p^T S q + q^T S q$$

> Now how can I find a $p $ such that this represents the constant zero function?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

> Here is how I tried to calculate the derivative of the function at a
> given point $p $
>
> To begin with, my definition of a derivative of a map $m$ from
> $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ at a point $p$ is a linear map $A$ from
> $\mathbb R^n $ to $\mathbb R$ such that
>
> $$\lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{|m(p+h) - m(p) - Ah|}{|h|}=0$$
>
> My approach is to differentiate the two maps $p \mapsto p^Tg $ and $p
>  \mapsto p^TS p$ individually and then add those two functions.  And we
> differentiate them by finding a function that "fits" the definition
> given above.
>
> Since the map $p \mapsto p ^T g$ is linear it is immediate that
>
> $$\lim _{h \to 0 } \frac {|((p+h)^T g - p^T g - h^T g | } {|h | } =
>  \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{0}{|h|} $$
>
> and thus that the map is its own derivative.
>
> For the second term I assume that $S$ is symmetric [a similar
> derivation would work otherwise]. Then since
>
> $$(p+h)^T S (p+h) = p^T S p + 2 p^T S h + h^T S h$$
>
> we have simarily as above that
>
> $$\lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{|(p+h)^T S (p+h) - p^TS p - (2 p^T S h + h^T S
>  h)| }{|h|}= \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{0}{|h|}=0$$
>
> and so the mat $q \mapsto p^T S q + q^T S q$ would be a derivative at
> the point $p$ of the map $q \mapsto q^T S q$.
>
> Then combining those two derivatives we get the map
>
> $$q \mapsto q^Tg + 2 p^T S q + q^T S q$$
>
> is the derivative of $$q \mapsto q^T g + q^T S q$$
>
> at the point $p$.

**SECOND EDIT**

I found the error I made above. Since the map

$$q \mapsto q^T S q $$

isn't linear we cannot have it in the derivative of the function

$$q \mapsto q^T S q $$

as this would make the map I stated as the derivative at the point $p $, namely $q \mapsto p^T S q + q^T S q$, nonlinear.

Insted we simply use that $\lim _{h \to 0 } h^T S h = 0$ (see [here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3542464/given-h-in-mathbb-rn-is-it-true-that-lim-h-to-0-fracht-s-h-h) and thus we have

$$\lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{|(p+h)^T S (p+h) - p^TS p - 2 p^T S h | }{|h|}= \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{|h^T S h|}{|h|}=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have $p$ and $q$ in your formula ? The gradient should be something like $p\rightarrow g + (S+S^T) p$, then to set it to zero you get $p = -(S+S^T)^{-1} g=-\frac{1}{2} S^{-1} g$ assuming that it is full rank (otherwise you can use someting like the Moore Penrose inverse).

Comment: maybe to clarify: The derivative of a map $p \mapsto $ something is still a map $p \mapsto $ something else.

Comment: @P.Quinton I get that the derivative at a given point $p $ depends on $p $ - see the derivation I added above. You seem to arrive at the correct answer, but could you expand a little? Why do you calculate the gradient and not the derivative as I tried? And how is the gradient calculated?

Comment: In the $\mathbb R^n$ case, derivative doens't exist, instead you can compute derivative in one direction. If you do this is the directions $e_i$ the standard orthonormal basis vectors, then you get the gradient. You can check this out : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222894/how-to-take-the-gradient-of-the-quadratic-form

Answer (score 2):

First, let's check your answer. Suppose  $n=1$, so that $p, S$ and $g$ are also scalars. Your original map can be written as $$\phi(p) = pg + p^2 S.$$
Thus
$$\phi'(p) = g + 2p S,$$
which does not match your expression. In fact, I don't understand why you've defined it in terms of a different variable while keeping the old one in the expression.

Let now $\Phi(p) = p^T g + p^T S p$ be your actual expression to be differentiated. Another indication that you've done the differentiation incorrectly is the dimensionality, which is always good to check. Your expression for the derivative is a scalar, whereas $\Phi(p)$ is a scalar and  $p = (p_1, ..., p_n)$, so your answer should be an $n$-dimensional gradient with entries $\partial \Phi(p) / \partial p_i$.

The answer is 
$$\nabla \Phi(p) = g^T + 2p^T S,$$
which I've written as a row vector by convention. Check out Propositions 7 and 8 in [this document](https://atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf). You can solve the equation now.