# Minimum value of $f(x) = x^{T}Ax$ when $A$ is symmetric and positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

So if $A$ is symmetric positive definite, how can we show that the graph of:

$f(x) = x^{T}Ax$ is concave up. Furthermore, what is the minimum value of this function?

Comment: The graphical representation (a generalized paraboloid) is **convex**, not concave. proof : the Hessian of $f$, i.e., $A$, is positive definite...

Comment: Minimum or minimizer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First observe that given $x,y$ and $\lambda\in [0,1]$ you have
\begin{align*}
f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) &= (\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)^T A (\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\\
&= \lambda^2 x^T A x + (1-\lambda)^2 y^TAy +\lambda (1-\lambda) x^T A y + \lambda (1-\lambda) y^T A x\\
\end{align*}
Now the last two terms can be bounded in a nice way, indeed since $A$ is positive definite, you have $0\leq (x-y)^T A (x-y) = x^T A x + y^T A y - x^TAy-y^TAx$ so that $x^TAy+y^TAx\leq x^TAx+y^TAy$. Inserting that in the above equation you get
\begin{align*}
f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) &\leq \lambda^2 x^T A x + (1-\lambda)^2 y^TAy +\lambda (1-\lambda) x^T A x + \lambda (1-\lambda) y^T A y\\
&= \lambda x^T A x+(1-\lambda) y^TAy\\
&= \lambda f(x) +(1-\lambda) f(y)
\end{align*}
So that $f$ is **convex**.

If you look at $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^{T}Ax - x^{T}b$, we know it is convex since it is basically $1/2 \cdot f$ plus something linear. So to minimize it, it is enough to set the gradient to $0$. The gradient is
\begin{align*}
\nabla g(x) &= \frac{1}{2} (A^T x+Ax)-b\\
&= Ax-b
\end{align*}
This is of course equal to $0$ when $x=A^{-1}b$.

Comment: Sorry but how does the first part show that f is convex? And how do you take the gradient of a matrix?

Comment: The definitions of convexity is for all $x,y$ and $\lambda\in [0,1]$, you have $f(lambda x+(1-\lambda) y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)$. For the gradient of the matrix, you are suppose to take the derivative element-wise, for linear and quadratic expressions there is a shortcut, check this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222894/how-to-take-the-gradient-of-the-quadratic-form

Answer (score 1):

Concave up actually means that the function is convex. We can check if a function is convex by looking at the hessian.
$$\
f(x) = x^TAx \\
H = 2A
$$
Since, the hessian is psd. We can conclude that the function is convex. For convex functions minimizer is given by $\nabla f(x^*) = 0$. For convex functions local minimizer is global minimizer.
Hope this helps.