# Gradient and Hessian of the product of two quadratic forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, quadratic-forms, hessian-matrix, scalar-fields

Let $Q, R \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $Q, R \succ 0$. Let $g\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right) : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$g\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{x}^{T}Q\boldsymbol{x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{x}^{T}R\boldsymbol{x}\right)$$

I want to find the gradient and the Hessian  of $g\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)$.

---

**What I tried so far**

To find the gradient and the Hessian using the derivative rules and got the following:

[image]

but while I notice (2nd element of the last row at the hessian calculation Ive got the term $2R\boldsymbol{x}\cdot Q\boldsymbol{x}$ which is column vector times another column vector and that's obviously a mistake.on my calculations product rule of gradient but I don't sure if It's a valid rule at matrix calculus. So, how can I calculate the gradient and the hessian  of $g\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)$?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894/339790)

Answer (score 3):

The individual terms are easy to handle:
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\p{\partial}
\alpha &= \tfrac{1}{2}x^TQx,
\qquad \frac{\p\alpha}{\p x} &= Qx,
\qquad \frac{\p^2\alpha}{\p x\,\p x^T} &= Q
\\
\beta &= \tfrac{1}{2}x^TRx,
\qquad \frac{\p\beta}{\p x} &= Rx,
\qquad \frac{\p^2\beta}{\p x\,\p x^T} &= R \\
\\
}$$
The calculation for their product is straight forward:
$$\eqalign{
\pi &= \alpha\beta \\
\\
\frac{\p\pi}{\p x}
 &= \beta\frac{\p\alpha}{\p x}
  + \alpha\frac{\p\beta}{\p x} \\
 &= \beta Qx \;+\; \alpha Rx \\
\\
\frac{\partial^2\pi}{\p x\,\p x^T}
 &= \beta\fracLR{\p^2\alpha}{\p x\,\p x^T}
  + \fracLR{\p\beta}{\p x} \fracLR{\p\alpha}{\p x^T}
  + \fracLR{\p\alpha}{\p x} \fracLR{\p\beta}{\p x^T}
  + \alpha\fracLR{\p^2\beta}{\p x\,\p x^T} \\
 &= \beta Q \;+\; Rxx^TQ \;+\; Qxx^TR \;+\; \alpha R \\
}$$

---

#### Update

This update addresses ordering issues raised in the comments.

Differentials are often the best approach for matrix calculus problems because, unlike gradients, they satisfy a simple product rule:
$$\eqalign{
d(A\star B)
 &= (A+dA)\star(B+dB) \;\;-\;\; A\star B \\
 &= dA\star B + A\star dB \\
}$$
where
$A$ is a {scalar, vector, matrix, tensor},
$B$ is a {scalar, vector, matrix, tensor}, and
$\star$ is **any** product which is compatible with $A$ and $B.\;$ This includes the Kronecker, Hadamard/elementwise, Frobenius/trace and dyadic/tensor products, as well as the Matrix/dot product.

**IFF** the product commutes, you can rearrange the product rule to
$$d(A\star B) = B\star dA + A\star dB$$
The Hadamard and Frobenius products always commute. The other products are commutative only in special situations. For example the Kronecker product commutes if either $A$ or $B$ is a scalar, and the dot product commutes if both $A$ and $B$ are real vectors.

The differential and the gradient are related and can be derived from one another, i.e.
$$\frac{\p\alpha}{\p x} = Qx
\quad\iff\quad d\alpha = (Qx)^Tdx = x^TQ\,dx$$
Let's examine one of the terms in the preceding hessian calculation.

First calculate its differential, and then its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 y &= \alpha(Rx) = (Rx)\alpha 
  \qquad \big({\rm the\,scalar\star vector\,product\,commutes}\big) \\
dy &= \alpha(R\,dx) + (Rx)\,d\alpha \\
   &= \alpha R\,dx \;\;\,+ Rx\;x^TQ\,dx \\
   &= (\alpha R+Rx\,x^TQ)\,dx \\
\frac{\p y}{\p x} &= \alpha R+Rx\,x^TQ \\
}$$

Comment: where I can find the rules of derivatives according to $x^T$ (a row vector)?
(I know the rules of derivatives according to x)

Comment: ( i guess its not same as derivatives according to $x$)

Comment: and, in the 2'nd term , why did you change the order of $\alpha,\beta$? here what i did: [link](https://imgur.com/EVbfjjw) it became matrix plus scalar and that's is incorrect.

Comment: Here's how to handle the transposed gradients  
$$\eqalign{
&1)\quad\;\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x^T}
 &= \left(\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x}\right)^T \\
&2)\;\;\frac{\partial^2\beta}{\partial xx^T}
 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x^T}\right) \\
}$$ As for changing the order, since $(\alpha,\beta)$ are scalars they can be moved to any convenient position without changing the value of an expression.

Comment: $\alpha,\beta$ are scalar but  $\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}},\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}}$ are vectors , and I don't think you can just change their order.here what I did and encounter the same issue again: [link] (https://ibb.co/KXjY8Bs)

Comment: thanks for all the support!
just to be sure,
here what I did : https://ibb.co/F7gYMyq
originally I used product rule at (1) and got a dimensional error.
but,at (2)  I used product rule with commutative property I got the right answer.(without a dimensional error)
I think I've got a mistake while using the product rule. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following: $g(x)$ can be rewritten as
$$
g(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^nQ_{ij}x_ix_j\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^nR_{ij}x_ix_j\right)
$$
where $Q_{ij}$ and $R_{ij}$ are the coefficients of the matrices $Q$ and $R$. Now you can proceed similarly as you did, taking derivative with respect to $x_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n$:
$$ 
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_k}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\sum_{i,j=1}^nQ_{ij}x_ix_j\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^nR_{ij}x_ix_j\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^nQ_{ij}x_ix_j\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\sum_{i,j=1}^nR_{ij}x_ix_j\right).
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks!
I did that and the gradient is the same as the previous calculation,but what about the hessian?It's suppose to look like this ? (after the calculations)?
$\nabla^{2}g\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{x}^{T}Q\boldsymbol{x}\right)R+\left(\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{x}^{T}R\boldsymbol{x}\right)Q$