# How to derive the Lyapunov Equation?

Tags: matrix-calculus, lyapunov-functions

I have a linear dynamical system:
$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = Ax$ with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$.

I consider a quadratic function $V(x) = x^T P x$ where $P \in \mathbb{R} ^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric matrix, i.e., $P^T = P$.

I want to show that:

$\dot{V} = \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x} \dfrac{dx}{dt} = x^T(A^TP + PA)x$.

Which rules do I need and how do I do it?

P.S.: I tried to use the findings in this post, but I can not reach the final equation: [How to take the gradient of the quadratic form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222894/how-to-take-the-gradient-of-the-quadratic-form)

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Yes it is a substep of the so called "Lyapunov Equation". This final form I have given is from a control theory book. So yes, this is the final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V'=x'^TPx+x^TPx'=(Ax)^TPx+x^TPAx=x^T(A^TP+PA)x$.