# Derivative of matrix trace

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I have konwn the derivative of matrix trace to matirx. However, is there a expression representing the derivative of matrix trace to vector.

For instant, matrix $P\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$ and vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$. $d,n \in \mathbb{R}^{+} $.

$f(x)=trace(PP^Txx^T)$.

Question: What is the answer of $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$?

Thanks a lot! : )

Comment: where do you get stuck?

Comment: $\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{trace}}$Note: $x^T PP^T x$ is just a $1\times1$ matrix (can be treated as a scalar), so $\tr\left(x^T PP^T x\right)=x^T PP^T x$. Then see e.g. [How to take the gradient of the quadratic form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222894/how-to-take-the-gradient-of-the-quadratic-form).