# Get wrong answer on $\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^{\top} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$ when using graph

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inner-products, quadratic-forms, scalar-fields

I can use the *product rule* to obtain $\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^{\top} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{x}^{\top} \frac{\partial \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}+(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x})^{\top} \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$, and get the right result $\mathbf{x}^{\top}\left(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}^{\top}\right)$. Here $x$ is a vector, $A$ is a matrix that is not a function of $x$.

However, when I try to calculate by using a graph, the result is different. I am not sure at which step I made the mistake. Please point out where I made it wrong. I used the graph attached (***red*** numbers are the derivatives) and the equations as follows.

[image: the graph]

Let $
q_{2}=q_{1}x$, $q_{1}=(A^{T} x)^{T}$,  and $k=A^Tx$. I want to find $\frac{d q_{2}}{d x}$

$\frac{d q_{2}}{d x}=\frac{\partial q_{2}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial q_{2}}{\partial q_{1}} \frac{\partial q_{1}}{\partial x}= q_{1}+x \frac{\partial q_{1}}{\partial x}= q_{1}+x \frac{\partial q_{1}}{\partial k} \frac{\partial k}{\partial x}  =x^TA+xIA^T = x^TA+xA^T \ne x^{\top}\left({A}+{A}^{\top}\right)$, $I$ is the NxN identity matrix.

The result I got here is different. I know it is not correct, but I couldn't figure out where I lost it.

Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Thank you, I've just checked the link out. It does provide some useful info, but I still don't know where I got it wrong in my proof!

Comment: Your notation is confusing. You use the exact same notation for the gradient and for the Jacobian.

Comment: Can you clarify it? It would be a great help for me because I'm new to this. Thank you!

Comment: $\frac{d q_{2}}{d x}=\frac{\partial q_{2}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial q_{2}}{\partial q_{1}} \frac{\partial q_{1}}{\partial x}$ is not correct. Where does this comes from?

Comment: Note that $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \mathbf{x}^{\top} \mathbf{A} \,\mathbf{x}$ is a scalar field, whereas $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}$ is a vector field.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: I use the chain rule for total derivatives (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) for d(f (x, q1)/dx. What should be the correct answer?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Thank you for the clarification. Do you mean I got it wrong because I mixed scalar field and vector field together? Sorry, I still don't get it.

Comment: @Catbuilts Can you explain how you are using the "graph" to calculate the derivative? I don't get the boxes. If you are using a PDF/Textbook/Video for this purpose, I'd like to see it so I can explain it with the benefit of knowing that source, which will be more helpful for you.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Thank you for your help. I follow the vector calculus from this book: https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf , and the graph on page 162. I don't know if it makes sense to use the graph with vector or not. Please show me where I got it wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @Catbuilts Will surely have a look, unless the answer below is satisfactory.

Comment: @teresa: thank you, Teresa. It is more clear to me now after reading the answer below. Again, thanks for your time and consideration!

Comment: @Catbuilts You are welcome! I spent some time looking at the question, then decided the answer below was well written enough. +1 to your question, and look forward to interacting with you on the site. Always remember to utilize the chain rule carefully in the multivariable situation, is the takeaway from this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line
$$\frac{d q_{2}}{d x}=\frac{\partial q_{2}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial q_{2}}{\partial q_{1}} \frac{\partial q_{1}}{\partial x}= q_{1}+x \frac{\partial q_{1}}{\partial x}=\dots$$
In terms of dimensions of matrices, it looks to me like you have written
$$ [1\times n] = [1\times n] + [1\times n][n\times n] = [1\times n] + [n\times 1][n\times n] = \dots $$
because  $x$ is a column vector. The product of matrices $[n\times 1][n\times n]$ is not defined, so there is an error here.

Let me try to rewrite in more explicit notation (I identify $\mathbb R^n$ with column vectors $\mathbb R^{n\times 1}$)

\begin{align} q&:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R,&q(x) &= x^TAx,\\
q_1&: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^{1\times n}, & q_1(x) &= (A^Tx)^T = x^TA,\\
q_2&:\mathbb R^{1\times n} \times \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R, & q_2(a,b) &= ab
\end{align}
Thus
$$q(x) = q_2(q_1(x),x)$$
Since there are subtly different spaces involved here, I'll elect to use a notation that works for arbitrary spaces, namely  the Frechet derivative $d$ which always satisfies the chain rule
$$ d(f\circ g)(x)[h] = df(g(x))[dg(x)[h]],$$
and then the only game is to figure out what spaces each differential belongs to.

Letting $\partial$ denote a partial Frechet derivative, we have
$$ dq(x)[h]= \partial_aq_2(q_1(x),x)[dq_1(x)[h]] + \partial_b q_2(q_1(x),x)[h].$$

Now, $q_1$ is linear, and $q_2$ is separately linear in each variable. For any linear map $L$, the Frechet derivative $dL(x)[h]=L(h)$. (The nice thing is that this covers multiplication of matrices on the left and on the right.) Thus for $h\in\mathbb R^n$ and $v\in\mathbb R^{1\times n}$,

\begin{align} 
dq_1(x)[h]&=q_1(h)=h^TA,\\
\partial_a q_2(a,b)[v]&= vb,\\
\partial_b q_2(a,b)[h]&= ah.
\end{align}
therefore \begin{align}
 dq(x)h&=dq_1(x)[h]x + q_1(x)h\\
&=h^T Ax + x^TA h \\
&= x^TA^Th +x^TAh \\
&= x^T(A^T+A)h = ((A^T+A)x)\cdot h
\end{align}
and finally we can read the Jacobian from the final line:
$$ \frac {dq}{dx}(x) = x^T(A^T+A).$$
(And, the gradient vector is its transpose $\nabla q(x) = (A^T+A)x$.)

Equivalently, one has to understand that the Jacobian of a map $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^{1\times n}$ acts **on the right**: if $g$ is $\mathbb R^{1\times n}$-valued, then
$ f(x+h) \approx f(x) + \frac{df}{dx}(x)h $ cannot make sense by dimension counting (remember $h$ is a column vector). So we are forced to accept that the correct approximation is $f(x+h)\approx f(x) + h^T \frac{df}{dx}(x)$. What this means is that **the order of terms in chain rule is reversed!** Indeed, the standard chain rule formula for the composition of a $\mathbb R^{n\times 1}$-vector valued function $f=f(y)$ and $g=g(x)$ is
$$ \frac{d(f\circ g)}{dx}(x) = \frac{df}{dy}(g(x))\frac{dg}{dx}(x)$$
If we take the matrix transpose of this equation, we obtain the chain rule for row-vector-valued functions $h=f^T$:
$$\frac{d(h\circ g)}{dx}(x) = \left(\frac{dg}{dx}(x)\right)^T\frac{dh}{dy}(g(x)).$$

A similar issue occurs in the above where the input is the row vector, and the approximation for $q_2$ reads
$ q_2(a+v,b)\approx q_2(a,b) + v \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial a}(a,b)$. Hence (and I think deriving from first principles is easiest)
\begin{align} q_2(q_1(x+h),b)&\approx q_2(q_1(x),b) + (q_1(x+h)-q_1(x)) \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial a}(q_1(x),b) 
\\&\approx q_2(q_1(x),b) + h^T\frac{dq_1}{dx}(x) \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial a}(q_1(x),b)
\\& = q_2(a,b) +  \frac{\partial q_2^T}{\partial a}(q_1(x),b)\frac{dq_1^T}{dx}(x)h \end{align}  The correct chain rule is therefore, as painful as it seems,
$$\frac{dq}{dx}(x)= \frac{\partial q_2^T}{\partial a}(q_1(x),x)\frac{dq_1^T}{dx}(x) + \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial b}(q_1(x),x)$$

It would be easier IMO to avoid this mess by not using a $\mathbb R^{1\times n}$-valued function.

Comment: very useful explanation, especially the last part! I have a follow-up: are gradient and jacobian always transpose when they are vectors (The part you say "and the gradient vector is its transpose...")?

Comment: glad to hear you found it useful! It is usually a transpose to me, but it is one of those things that not everyone agrees on.

Comment: I am reading on Numerator Layout and Denominator Layout. Is that related?  As far as I understand, if we use Numerator Layout for f: N->1, jacobian is a row vector (1xN), and the gradient is its transpose (Nx1), but if we use Denominator Layout, they should be the same. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I think that’s basically the issue. If I’m not wrong the book calls Jacobian and gradient the same thing. Basically if a calculation you see somewhere looks wrong, this is one of the things you need to check

Comment: Thank you. In the 2 formulas at the end, I think it should be `df/dg` and `dh/dg`.

Comment: @Catbuilts Yes, usually, when discussing chain rule, you should have two different variable names e.g. $f=f(y)$ and $g=g(x)$ and then $d(f\circ g)/dx(x) = df/dy (g(x)) dg/dx(x)$. I'll figure out how to reword it. Thank you for the careful reading!