# Gradient of $\mbox{trace}(Axx^TB)$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms, scalar-fields

I am trying to find the gradient

$$\nabla \mbox{trace}(Axx^TB)$$

where both $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices, and $x$ is an $n$-length column vector

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem in order to lead me to the solution. I know that $xx^T$ forms an $n \times n$ matrix with squares along the diagonal, but how do both other matrices multiply with that to achieve the trace?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\phi
=\mathrm{tr}
\left( \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{B} \right)
=\mathrm{tr}
\left( \mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}
\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T \right)
$$

The differential writes
\begin{eqnarray}
d\phi
&=& (\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A})^T
:d(\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T) \\
&=& 2\mathrm{sym}(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}) \mathbf{x}
:d\mathbf{x}
\end{eqnarray}

where
$\mathrm{sym}(\mathbf{C})= \frac12
\left( \mathbf{C}+\mathbf{C}^T \right)$
and the colon operator : denotes the Frobenius inner product.

The gradient is the vector
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{x}}=
2\mathrm{sym}(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}) \mathbf{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Given matrices ${\bf A}, {\bf B} \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$, let scalar field $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be defined by

$$ f ({\bf x}) := \mbox{tr} \left( {\bf A} {\bf x} {\bf x}^\top {\bf B} \right) = \mbox{tr} \left( {\bf x}^\top {\bf B} {\bf A} {\bf x} \right) = {\bf x}^\top {\bf B} {\bf A} {\bf x} $$

Note that $f$ is a **quadratic form**. The gradient of $f$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894/339790)

$$ \nabla_{{\bf x}} f ({\bf x}) = \color{blue}{\left({\bf B} \, {\bf A} + {\bf A}^\top {\bf B}^\top \right) {\bf x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{trace}(Axx^TB) 
= \langle Ax, B^Tx \rangle 
= \sum_{i\in[n]} (Ax)_{i} \times (B^Tx)_{i} 
= \sum_{i\in[n]} (A_i \cdot x) \times (B^i \cdot x),$
where $A_i$ is the $i$-th **row** of A,
and $B^i$ is the $i$-th **column** of B.

$\langle X,Y \rangle = \operatorname{trace}(X^T Y)$ (Euclidean [matrix] inner product)

$x \cdot y = \sum_i x_i \times y_i$ (Euclidean [vector] inner product)