# Correct definition of derivatives of higher dimensions - Derivative of quadratic form - From the perspective of notation

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, quadratic-forms, scalar-fields

I am studying optimal control (for an introductory course) and we have to know the derivatives of quadratic forms.

Out teacher said that the following are true:
$$\frac{\partial Ax}{\partial x} = A^T $$
$$ \frac{\partial x^TAx}{\partial x} = (A^T+A)x $$

from what i gathered (using this source: https://www.kamperh.com/notes/kamper_matrixcalculus13.pdf )
the derivative of a scalar function is defined as:
$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \\ ... \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}  \end{bmatrix} $$

however, i have been taught the derivative so far as (also presented here http://michael.orlitzky.com/articles/the_derivative_of_a_quadratic_form.xhtml) :
$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}, ... , \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}  \end{bmatrix} $$

This way of thinking about the derivative is combatible witht he taylor series:
$$ f(x+h) = f(x) + \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} \cdot h $$

And the previous derivatives now become (for combatible dimensions. See also the second link where the folling are prooved) :
$$\frac{\partial Ax}{\partial x} = A $$
$$ \frac{\partial x^TAx}{\partial x} = x^T(A^T+A) $$

Is someone wrong? If that is not the case, what is the motivation (and advantages ?) for the second definition?

Comment: Derivatives?  Call them what they are — Jacobian and gradient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take the gradient of the quadratic form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222894/how-to-take-the-gradient-of-the-quadratic-form)

Comment: I liked the proofs from here better (http://michael.orlitzky.com/articles/the_derivative_of_a_quadratic_form.xhtml it is also in the main question). My question has to do with notation mainly, and i will clarify it in the title.

Comment: Variants of this question have been asked [dozens](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/222894) (if not hundreds) of times.  You could try to find previous questions on it and try to add to them instead of starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivatives are just the transposes of what your teacher said. Both are correct; they just use different conventions of matrix differentiation. In general, you may find the [wiki rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) helpful, which give rules for both conventions.