# Differential of quadratic form

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, quadratic-forms, differential, scalar-fields

I'm having trouble understanding this:
if $\phi(x)=x^{T}Ax$, where $A$ is a matrix of constraints. Then, the differential of $\phi$:
$\mathrm{d} \phi=(\mathrm{d} x)^{T} A x+x^{T} A \mathrm{~d} x=x^{T} A^{T} \mathrm{d} x+x^{T} A \mathrm{~d} x=x^{T}\left(A+A^{T}\right) \mathrm{d} x$.

I'm having trouble understanding this step: why is $(\mathrm{d} x)^{T} A x=x^{T} A^{T} \mathrm{d} x$?

I find it interesting because based on the rule:
$$
(AB)^{T}=B^{T}A^{T} 
$$
we have
$$
(\mathrm{d} x)^{T} (A x)=[(Ax)^{T} \mathrm{d} x]^{T}
$$
**Therefore $(\mathrm{d} x)^{T} A x=x^{T} A^{T} \mathrm{d} x$ essentially is saying that $[(Ax)^{T} \mathrm{d} x]^{T}=(Ax)^{T} \mathrm{d} x$**

**Showing me why this is the case can help me understand this question a lot.**

I do know [thispost](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222894/how-to-take-the-gradient-of-the-quadratic-form), but I don't understand why we need chain rule here, because the chain rule is:
Let $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$ be differentiable at $t$ and suppose that $z=f(x, y)$ is differentiable at the point $(x(t), y(t))$. Then $z=f(x(t), y(t))$ is differentiable at $t$ and
$$
\frac{d z}{d t}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{d t}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \frac{d y}{d t}
$$

there's no involvement of another variable t at a lower-level than x & y. There is just one level x here.

Thank you all in advance for your answers.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894/339790)

Comment: Since it is a scalar its transpose is equal to itself.

Comment: but A' = A only if A is symmetric, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recover it easily from
$$
\phi(x)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij} x_i x_j
$$

$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_k} = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj} x_j + \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ik} x_i  = [(A+A')x ]_k
$$

So, the differential becomes
$$
(D\phi)(x)(h) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i} h_i =x' (A+A')h
$$