# Minimizer of a convex quadratic function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, quadratic-programming

> Suppose that there is a positive definite matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, and a vector $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, then minimization of quadratic functions with linear terms can be done in closed form as $$\arg\min_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}_n }  \left( \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^\mathsf{T} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{x} \right) = \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{b}$$

---

I met this in a machine learning book. However, the book didn't provide a proof. I wonder why this can be well-formed. Hope that someone can help me with it.  I find that many machine learning books like to skip all of the proofs, which made me uncomfortable.

Comment: The minimisation of *which* quadratic forms? What's the actual equation you're attemting to solve? That said, I am fairly certain I have seen this on Wiki and that it uses some straightforward first and second differentiation techniques

Comment: Start with the symmetry of $\bf A$. Then use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894/339790).

Answer (score 3):

One way of proving this is to "complete the square":
$$
\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x^\top A x - b^\top x}=\frac{1}{2}\left( \mathbf{\big(x-A^\mathrm{-1}b\big)^\top A \big(x-A^\mathrm{-1}b\big) - b^\top A^\mathrm{-1}b}\right)\ .
$$
Because $\ \mathbf{A}\ $ is positive definite this is never less than $\ {-}\frac{1}{2}\,\mathbf{b^\top A^\mathrm{-1}b}\ $, and it attains that value when $\ \mathbf{x= A^\mathrm{-1}b}\ $.