# Stuck while differentiating $x\mapsto\|x\|^2 + \lambda{\|Ax - b\|}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, scalar-fields

I want to differentiate the following equation

$$ x \mapsto \|x\|^2 + \lambda{\|Ax - b\|}^2 $$

where the real symmetric matrix $A$ is not invertible. I have decomposed $A$ using the spectral theorem, but stuck on how to then differentiate the function w.r.t to $x$. The function then looks like

$$ x \mapsto \|x\|^2 + \lambda {\left\| Q B Q^{-1} x - b \right\|}^2 $$

How do I differentiate this now?

Comment: I know this is basic, but I am new to matrix calculus. I know how to differentiate the first term, but not sure how to expand the norm of a matrix (which is the second term)

Comment: If $x$ and $b$ are vectors, then $Ax-b$ is also a vector, so $\|Ax-b\|$ is a vector norm, not a matrix norm.

Comment: Yes! Understood my mistake. Thank you. Deleting this ig now

Comment: Assuming this is the Euclidean norm, the differential at $a$ of $x\mapsto\|x\|^2$ is $h\mapsto 2\langle a,h\rangle.$ For the other summand, use this and the chain rule.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894/339790)

Comment: Easiest to write out the sums explicitly, then differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, introduce the variable
$$\eqalign{
w &= \LR{Ax-b} \qiq dw = A\:dx \\
}$$
and the Frobenius product $(:)$ which has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \;=\; \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
Use the above notation to rewrite the objective function $(\phi)$
and calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= x:x + \l w:w \\
d\phi &= 2x:dx + 2\l w:\c{dw} \\
 &= 2x:dx + 2\l\LR{Ax}:\CLR{A\:dx} \\
 &= 2\LR{x+\l A^TAx} : dx \\
\grad{\phi}{x} &= 2\LR{x+\l A^TAx} \\
}$$
Note that $A^{-1}$ is not needed, only $A^TA,$ which always exists.