# How to calculate the directional derivative of $x \mapsto \frac12 \|Ax\|_2^2$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

Given the matrix $A \in \Bbb R^{k \times n}$, let the scalar field $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be defined by $$f(x) := \frac12 \|Ax\|_2^2$$ Calculate the directional derivative $\partial_{v}f(x)$, $v \in \Bbb R^n$ and deduce that $\nabla f(x) = A^T A x$.

---

Attempt:

$$\partial_{v}f(x) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+tv) - f(x)}{t}\implies \partial_{v}f(x) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\|Ax + t Av\|^2 - \|Ax\|^2}{2t}$$

I am unsure how to proceed from here since, to my understanding, $\|Ax + tAv\|^2 - \|Ax\|^2$ cannot be simplified to $\|tAv\|^2$. If it could, $\partial_{v}f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\|Av\|^2$.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3357120/339790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$|Ax|^2=x^T A^T Ax$$
where $A^T$ means the transpose of $A$.

By defenition,
\begin{align}
&|Ax+tAv|^2-|Ax|^2\\
&=(x^TA^T+tv^TA^T)(Ax+tAv)-x^T A^T Ax\\
&=x^TA^TAx+tx^TA^TAv+tv^TA^TAx+t^2v^TA^TAv-x^T A^T Ax\\
&=tx^TA^TAv+tv^TA^TAx+t^2v^TA^TAv
\end{align}
Divided by $\frac{1}{2t}$, and let $t\to0$, we obtain
$$\frac{1}{2t}\left({tx^TA^TAv+tv^TA^TAx+t^2v^TA^TAv}\right)=\frac12(x^TA^TAv+v^TA^TAx+tv^TA^TAv)$$
and this tends to
$$\frac12(x^TA^TAv+v^TA^TAx)$$
Finally note that
$$x^TA^TAv=v^TA^TAx=\langle Ax,Av\rangle$$
as real inner product. In conclusion, we have
$$\partial_{v}f(x) = \langle Ax,Av\rangle$$
On the other hand, we can also rewrite $\langle Ax,Av\rangle$ as $\langle A^TAx,v\rangle$, because
$$\langle Ax,Av\rangle=v^T\left(A^TAx\right)$$
Since this is a differentiable function (on $\mathbb R^n$), a theorem in Calculus tells us
$$\partial_{v}f(x)=\langle\nabla f(x),v\rangle$$
Hence $\nabla f(x) = A^T A x.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{|Ax+tAv|^2-|Ax|^2}{2t}=\frac{\langle Ax+tAv,Ax+tAv \rangle-\langle Ax, Ax \rangle}{2t}=$$ $$=\frac{2\langle tAv,Ax \rangle+\langle tAv, tAv \rangle}{2t}=\langle Av,Ax \rangle +\frac{t}{2} \langle Av,Av \rangle.$$
From here we can compute directly $f$'s gradient:
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)-\langle A^TA x,tv \rangle}{t}{=} ({\text{simplify } t's})=$$ $$=\lim_{t\to 0} \langle Av,Ax \rangle +\frac{t}{2} \langle Av,Av \rangle-\langle A^TA x,v \rangle=\lim_{t\to 0}\langle Av,Ax \rangle-\langle A^TA x,v \rangle=0$$ The last equality holds because the transpose has this property: $\langle v,Aw \rangle=\langle A^Tv,w \rangle.$

P.s. I can verify  in this way (namely with 1-dimensional limit) that  A^TA x its the gradient  because i know that that $f$ its already differentiable (composition of $C^\infty$ functions).